# Connector housing identification: Grow R307 Fingerprint Module

Tags: connector, identification

I'm trying to find the connector for the image shown below. It's from the R307 Fingerprint Module that can be found [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32853966097.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.7ef74c4drrwIIe). Any help will be appreciated.

[image: The connector]

Comment: Could be JST PH series connectors. What is the center-to-center spacing? 2mm? 0.1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mkeith's reply led me down a rabbit hole of JST connectors. Turns out this connector (1.25mm pitch) is actually a Molex PicoBlade (which is commonly confused with JST XH that also has 1.25mm pitch).