# Identify cable connector for fingerprint sensor

Tags: pcb, connector, identification, footprint

I want to create a custom PCB to which [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32602165473.html) fingerprint sensor will connect. The problem is that I cannot identify which connector it uses. The sellers on Amazon and other sites don't know about it.

Any help on how I can identify the name/footprint for the female connector which is compatible with this wire?

[image: image of connector]

Comment: FYI the connector on a similar (but I don't think identical) fingerprint reader, was identified in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/527817/101852) previous question. Even though that might not apply to yours, it might help future readers who find this question about fingerprint reader connectors, but actually have the one in that linked question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking your link, the bigger version of picture is available, so I paste it here in case of the link dying.

[image: JST]

This connector can be found under "JST" name, you would need to find the pitch, as they are available in many sizes, like 2.5mm, 2mm, 1mm and probably many other. When you have your device in hand, just measure the distance between pins and this is your pitch size.

EDIT:
I just realised you asked about female part, so it goes as "JST PCB mount female connector", maybe you can add "right angle" to have pins parallel to the PCB plane.